Prism.DryIoc on Nuget reference incompatible versions of Drylock
I am writing a Windows WPF application using Prism.DryIoc. When I load the latest Prism.DryIoc with NuGet, it loads DryIoc.dll Version 4.7.7. When I run the App, I get the following error:
Could not load file or assembly 'DryIoc, Version=5.4.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=dfbf2bd50fcf7768' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest
definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

It is thrown from the call to app.Run() in App.g.cs.
Why is it trying to load Version 5.4.3 if Version 4.7.7 was specified in the Nuget install?
I tried updating DryIoc to Version 5.4.3. It solves this problem, but generates another problem.
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'DryIoc.Rules
DryIoc.Rules.WithoutFastExpressionCompiler()'.'

According to what I've read in other conversations in StackExchange, this method was dropped for good reason in DryIoc.
Any ideas how to resolve this problem? Apparently I need verison 5.4.3 to run with the current version of Prism.DryIoc, but that version also tries to call a DryIoc method which no longer exists.

Which version of Prism do you use? You should only need Prism.DryIoc 8.1.97, Prism.Container.DryIoc is needed only for the paid versions (which are in prerelease as of now).
